# How many monitors can be hooked up to a Mac Mini?

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, thunderbolt

**How many monitors can be hooked up to a Mac Mini?**

I've only ever hooked a Mac Mini up to 2 monitors, but I'm interested in going up to at least 4. Is this even possible?

According to [Apple's Mac Mini feature description page](http://www.apple.com/mac-mini/features.html):

> You can daisy-chain up to six peripherals to a single Thunderbolt 2 port.

Does this mean that more than 2 monitors is possible?

[image: Mac Mini at the time of this writing]

Comment: 2 Thunderbolt displays might be the limit, but there's also the HDMI port… can you use it while you're also using the Thunderbolt port?

Comment: The graphics card have limitations too.  Are there enough pixels?

Answer (score 2):

Only one Mac Mini (to date) has supported three simultaneous monitors. The Mid 2011 Mac Mini (Macmini5,2) came with an AMD Radeon HD 6630M that was powerful enough to drive two Thunderbolt displays while simultaneously driving an HDMI display. [1](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219#dispnum)

The current Late 2012 Mac Mini, along with the other Mid 2011 Mac Minis, all have integrated Intel graphics that are only able to drive, at most, two Thunderbolt displays or one Thunderbold and one HDMI display.

Answer (score 0):

Intel Haswell can support 3 monitors, so when the new 2013 Mac Mini is finally released it may support 3 monitors as well.